# How can I change a row's background colour with nth-child inline?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, inline-styles

I have the following table:

```css
.table tbody tr:nth-child(4n+1),
.table tbody tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-default">
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td><td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td><td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td><td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td><td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td><td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td><td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td><td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column Data</td><td>Column Data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I can change the background colour of the nth row with CSS by doing:

```
.table tbody tr:nth-child(4n+1),
.table tbody tr:nth-child(4n+2) {
    background: rgb(247, 247, 247);
}
```

How can I do the same by changing the style of the table inline? I have tried to replace

```
<table class="table table-sm">
```

with

```
<table style="tr:nth-child(4n+1){background: rgb(247, 247, 247)}; tr:nth-child(4n+2){background: rgb(247, 247, 247)}" class="table table-sm">
```

but it does not work. I am a bit confused about the correct syntax.

Comment: You cannot because `style` attribute only accepts CSS properties, not selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inline style relates only to the element in whose tag it is written (i.e. without a selector). You'd have to write the background definition into each single `td` to which it should apply...

As an in-between solution (between external stylesheet and inline style), you can add a `<style>` tag to your HTML code and put the CSS rules in there.